# htaccess to remove the GET params, but still pass the value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have it set to redirect `www.foo.***/2` to `www.foo.***/index.php?id=2`, but i am trying to get it to redirect without displaying the URL.

I want the URL to stay as `www.foo.***/2` but atually deliver `www.foo.***/index.php?id=2`

my htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^$ h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/index.php [L]
ErrorDocument 404 h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/ERROR/
ErrorDocument 500 h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/SERVER/
RewriteRule ^(error)/([0-9A-Za-z+]+)?$ h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/index.php?action=ERROR [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(server)/([0-9A-Za-z+]+)?$ h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/index.php?action=SERVER [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z+]+)?$ h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

any help would be great thanks!

bo huttinger

thanks to awesome spamz protectionz, I subsituted stars for letters in the post

Comment: **UGH** its a `same domain` issue. even though the redirect was to the same server, it has the http in there and was doing the right thing by showing an external redirect!

Comment: So ... what is the current status -- is it solved or you sill need some help? -- it is unclear for me

Comment: solution: instead of using `h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]` use this: `/home/~user/folder/sub/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a 'same domain' issue. If you call a location on the same server, it doesn't rewrite the URL in the bar

solution: instead of using:

```
h**p://server/~user/folder/sub/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

use this:

```
/home/~user/folder/sub/index.php?id=$1 [L,NC]
```

hope this helps!